# C# Read Excel data that is linked to Oracle DB

Tags: c#, excel, oracle11g

How do you read data from an Excel.xslx that is linked to Oracle? I can read the entire sheet just fine using C# and print to the console window, however this data that is being pulled (and refreshed every so often) cannot be read as a named range or table. I have tested reading data as named ranges/tables in other workbooks (not being pulled from Oracle) just fine. I would prefer not to read the entire sheet. So my question is how i would refer to this linked data as a named range or table in my sql query using C#, or if there is some other way to just read that linked data from Excel? Code is posted below followed by the output error (which has no build warnings/errors), 'PersonTable' is the named range i gave to the data that is being pulled from oracle11g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ReadExcelNamedRage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.12.0; data source=c:\\documents and settings\\jhamandi\\desktop\\hrOracleTest.xlsx;extended properties=Excel 8.0";
            //Select using a Named Range
            string selectString = "SELECT * FROM PersonTable";

            //Select using a Worksheet name
           // string selectString = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection opened");
                OleDbDataReader theData = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (theData.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2}) - {3} ({4})", theData.GetDouble(0),
                        theData.GetString(1), theData.GetString(2), theData.GetString(3), theData.GetString(4));
                   // Console.WriteLine("Writing");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Connection opened
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object `PersonTable`. Ma
ke sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctl
y. If `PersonTable` is not a local object, check your network connection or cont
act the server administrator.
Connection closed
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: What version of excel are you using? Because your connection string is for Excel 97-2003 (properties=Excel 8.0), but you are calling a `xlsx` which is for 2007+ format. Also, you say the data is not readable as a table but yet you call for `PersonTable`

Comment: It is Excel 2010. I can create a completely different workbook (or dummy data in another sheet) and read that as a named range/table then writeline to the console. For whatever reason I cannot do that for the data that is being pulled from Oracle, the only thing that is working for me to read that is by reading the entire sheet which i do not want to do.